# Back-transforming forecast points and error bounds from a VAR model applied to alr-transformed compositional time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, vector-autoregression, compositional-data, back-transformation

### The data

I have a `k=3` compositional time series from which I am trying to forecast future values.

The series is compositional in that at each time `t`, the series is a vector of three values which are non-negative proportions that sum up to 1.

### Modelling approach

I am modelling the data by:

- first applying an additive logistic transformation (alr) to the data
- and then modelling the resulting series using vector AR models (`VAR`)

This is one of possible approaches suggested in the literature ([here](https://www.scb.se/contentassets/f6bcee6f397c4fd68db6452fc9643e68/the-time-series-analysis-of-compositional-data.pdf))

Here is a reproducible example in `R`, with `n = 20`, where `s1`, `s2`, `s3` make up the original compositional time-series (D=3), and 
`alr1`, `alr2` the corresponding alr-transformed series (D-1).

```
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(s1= c(0.67, 0.56, 0.53, 0.71, 0.6, 0.5, 0.53, 0.58, 0.59, 0.56, 0.61, 0.56, 0.57, 0.66, 0.57, 0.46, 0.58, 0.38, 0.38, 0.52), s2 = c(0.22, 0.23, 0.22, 0.17, 0.17, 0.27, 0.15, 0.15, 0.24, 0.22, 0.1, 0.27, 0.12, 0.03, 0.03, 0.21, 0.18, 0.24, 0.3, 0.12), s3 = c(0.11, 0.2, 0.25, 0.12, 0.23, 0.23, 0.32, 0.27, 0.17, 0.22, 0.29, 0.17, 0.3, 0.31, 0.4, 0.33, 0.24, 0.38, 0.31, 0.35)))                   

library(compositions)

mydata[, c('alr1', 'alr2')] <- compositions::alr(mydata[c('s1', 's2', 's3')])
```

#### Problem

I need to back-transform the `alr` forecast and error bounds (sample space `R^(D-1)`) to the original scale (i.e., a compositional time-series whose sample space is `S^(D=3)`), but I am getting results that do not make sense.

**Questions:** Why is this the case? And how can I get around this problem?

#### Code and problematic results

```
library(compositions)
library(vars)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- forecast::msts(mydata, seasonal.period=c(7))

# estimate a VAR(1) model on the alr-transformed data (just as an example)
var1_m <- vars::VAR(y=mydata[,c('alr1', 'alr2')], p = 1, type = 'const')


# forecast next 10 timepoints
var1_fcst <- predict(var1_m, n.ahead = 10, orig=0, ci=0.95)
var1_fcst
plot(var1_fcst)

# Back-transform forecasts and their error bounds
# extract two sets of forecasts (alr1 and alr2)
fcst_list <- lapply(var1_fcst[['fcst']], function(x) as.data.frame(x))

# apply back transformation to forecast estimate points, and their lower and upper bounds respectively
fcst_probs <- do.call("cbind", lapply(c('fcst', 'lower', 'upper'), function(x) compositions::alrInv(cbind(fcst_list[[1]][x], fcst_list[[2]][x]))))

colnames(fcst_probs) <- c('s1_fcst', 's2_fcst', 's3_fsct','s1_lower', 's2_lower', 's3_lower', 's1_upper', 's2_upper', 's3_upper')

# transform as mts object
fcst_probs_mts <- forecast::msts(fcst_probs, seasonal.period=c(7), start=c(3,7))

print(fcst_probs_mts)
```

[image]

**The results make no sense**: lower and upper bounds do not include the forecast point, and upper bounds for `s3` are lower than its lower bounds.

Just to visualise the problem, a quick plot of the results on the original scale for `s1`:

```
# plot results on the original scale and 
s1_fcst <- cbind(mydata[, 's1'], fcst_probs_mts[, c('s1_fcst', 's1_lower', 's1_upper')]) 
colnames(s1_fcst) <- c('orig_s1', 's1_fcst', 's1_lower', 's1_upper')

s1_fcst %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]